# C++ test file generator generates inconsistent data

Tags: c++

This program is suppose to generate test files based on user provided parameters. The file simulate commands that have as first paramater *fileNumber*.  For example:

```
START 1
WRITE 1 1
WRITE 1 1
READ 1 1
START 2
READ 1 1
...
...
READ 2 1
END 1
WRITE 1 2
WRITE 1 2
READ 2 2
WRITE 1 1
WRITE 1 2
WRITE 1 2
WRITE 2 3
WRITE 2 4
WRITE 2 5
END 2
```

The problem is that the lines after `END fileNumber` should not no longer have any more operations on that *fileNumber*.

The sample textfile above was generated by the generator and demonstrates the problem: after line `END 1`, there are still multiple `WRITE 1 *`

Here the code:

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv){
  if(argc < 4){
      usage(argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // extract command line arguments
  std::stringstream ss;
  int diskCapacity = atoi(argv[1]);// ss << argv[1]; ss >> diskCapacity;
  int writeRatio = atoi(argv[2]);// ss << argv[2]; ss >> writeRatio;
  char *ofileName = argv[3];

  // validate writeRatio
  if( (writeRatio < 0) || (writeRatio > 100) ) {
      std::cerr << argv[0] << ": writeRatio out of range [0,100]: " << writeRatio << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  std::ofstream outfile;
  outfile.open(ofileName);

  // seed rng
  std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::minstd_rand rng(time.time_since_epoch().count());

  /***** generate simluation sequence *****/
  int diskSize = 0;
  std::vector<File> aliveFiles;
  int new_fid = 1;
  int nFilesCreated = 0;

  // create at least 1 file
  File f;
  f.id = new_fid++;
  f.size = 1;
  aliveFiles.push_back(f);
  diskSize++;
  nFilesCreated++;
  outfile << start(f.id) << std::endl;

  do {
      // start
      if( ((rng()%10) < 2) && (nFilesCreated < diskCapacity/4) ){
        // new file
        f.id = new_fid++;
        f.size = 1;

        // add to disk
        aliveFiles.push_back(f);
        diskSize++;
        nFilesCreated++;
        outfile << start(f.id) << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    // choose a file
    int new_fsize = -1;
    int new_fid = -1;
    if(!aliveFiles.empty()) {
        std::random_shuffle(aliveFiles.begin(), aliveFiles.end());
        new_fid = (aliveFiles.back()).id;
        new_fsize = (aliveFiles.back()).size;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
    // write
    if( (int)(rng() % 100) < writeRatio ) {
        // writeRatio% chance to write
        int block = 1 + (rng() % new_fsize);
        File newFile;
        if(block == new_fsize) {
            // writing new block
            diskSize++;
            new_fsize++;
            newFile.id = new_fid;
            newFile.size = new_fsize;
            aliveFiles.pop_back();
            aliveFiles.push_back(newFile);
        }
        outfile << write(newFile.id, block) << std::endl;
        continue;
    }

    // end/read
    if(rng() % 100 == 0) {
        // end
        aliveFiles.pop_back();
        outfile << end(new_fid) << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        if( (int)(rng() % 100) < (100-writeRatio) ){
            // (100-writeRatio)% chance to read
            if(new_fsize > 1) {
                int block = 1 + (rng() % (new_fsize-1));
                outfile << read(new_fid, block) << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
  } while(diskSize < diskCapacity);

  // check that all files have ended, if not then clean up
  while(!aliveFiles.empty()) {
      new_fid = (aliveFiles.back()).id;
      aliveFiles.pop_back();
      outfile << end(new_fid) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rather nasty.  If you look at the test data, you'll notice that the bad *fileNumber* happens only for `WRITE` lines and never for `READ` lines.

This narrows down the problem to this part of your code, where you used a variable `newFile` without initialising it first:

```
    // write
    if((int)(rng() % 100) < writeRatio) {
        // writeRatio% chance to write
        int block = 1 + (rng() % new_fsize);
        File newFile;                     //  <===== unitialized !!
        if(block == new_fsize) {          //  <===== what happens if this is false ?   
            // writing new block
            diskSize++;
            new_fsize++;
            newFile.id = new_fid;
            newFile.size = new_fsize;
            aliveFiles.pop_back();
            aliveFiles.push_back(newFile);
        }
    outfile << write(newFile.id, block) << std::endl; // <== OUCH, if the if condition failed you go here with random data in newFile !!   
        continue;
    }
```

Two alternatives to solve the problem:

- Just move the  `outfile<< ... ;` statement into the `if` block. The generated test file is then totally ok and consistent.  But the WRITE is happens only if `block==new_fsize` .
- Or move `newFile.id=new_fid;` and `newFile.size=new_fsize;` outside the  `if` block. But you then have to think if it's reasonnable to "write" on `newFile.id` without putting it in the `aliveFiles`.

Comment: Nice catch. I spent the whole night and no luck finding this bug.

Comment: @firefly Watch out for the new_fid variable. It's defined twice, once outside the do/while and once in. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @user4581301 this is a very good shot too !  Congratulations ! And very nasty too:  the first part of the loop body refers to the new_fid outside the loop, but the second part of the loop bod to the redefined one.   You probably saved firefly another night

Comment: It probably does what OP wants it to do since the inner new_fid shouldn't be pushed onto the stack until after the program's done with outer new_fid, but god help him-or-her if the some nifty optimization trick in the compiler has a better idea.